# Netbeans Property Sheet - Row Height

Tags: java, netbeans, properties, netbeans-platform, propertysheet

When creating the PropertySheet in the createProperties method of a BeanNode subclass, is there a way to change height of a *single* row? Or is there a way to tell the property to change its height according to its content? (There should be displayed a 64x64 valueIcon in the property, but parts of the height are cut off)

Answer (score 0):

A component can be resized by dragging small square resize handles that appear around its perimeter when it is selected.

To resize the First Name: and Surname: text fields and make them occupy two adjacent cells, complete the steps below:

- Control-click the two JTextField components to select them.
- With both JTextFields selected, position the cursor over the cells
  right edge, click and drag until the orange highlighted guideline
  embraces the adjacent cells in column 2 on the right.
- Release the cursor to resize the components.

  The First Name: and Surname: text fields are extended to span between the two cells as shown in the following illustration. The
  occupied cells are highlighted.

Comment: I want to do it in code and also these sheets are automatically created by netbeans platform and not in the GUI builder.